# Мелкие элементы в header лучше верстать через float или через inline-block?

Tags: html, css, float

Как лучше выстраивать такие мелкие элементы, как на скриншоте (логотип, поиск, закладки и т. д.) и почему?[image: header]

Comment: я предпочитаю inline-block, потому что он наиболее предсказуемый, но вообще, думаю, использовать нужно ту технологию, которая понятнее и больше нравится. Ну и конечно, учитывать всю нюансы конкретного проекта: поддерживаемые браузеры, адаптивность и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов. Например можно им всем задать свойство `display:inline-block;` Можно поиграться с float. Но, мне кажется, что сейчас лучше всего использовать flex (если не нужна поддержка в IE 9-).

```
.menu{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}
.menu__item{
 flex: 0 0 auto; 
}
```